# How to install OpenGL/GLUT libraries

Tags: opengl, command-line

I currently installed ubuntu 11.10 on my acer netbook. I have problem getting some packages I need. I am using the most updated version and have a wifi connection on my campus. This is what my instructor wishes for us to do:

1. select Applications/Accessories/Terminal on the Ubuntu desktop
2. type `ls /usr/include/GL` 
   if `glut.h gl.h` etc are there, great 
   if not, install it `sudo apt-get install libglut3-dev`
3. I then copied `program1.c` to the desktop
4. `cd desktop`
5. `gcc -lglut -lGLU program1.c`
   note l is a lower-case L, which means library in UNIX
6. `./a.out` to execute

I complete step 2, in which returns:

```
sudo: ls/brandon/include/GL: command not found
```

so from here I do the apt-get and try to install it but returns me with this:

```
E: Unable to locate package libglut3-dev
```

Does this have to do with my connection or is there something I need to be doing on my system for it to find the package and install it.  I'm really new to ubuntu and could use some help just getting started.

Comment: Step 2 was to type the command ls /usr/include/GL and not ls/brandon/include/GL. Not your user name but usr. There is a space between ls and the path /usr/include/GL. Because there is no space the terminal is seeing what you typed as a single command which does not exist and not a command followed by an option. You need to find out if there are files in the GL directory such as glut.h, gl.h and the rest. To get more information about the ls command type man ls - regards

Comment: Thank you, but I still seem to have a problem, upon entering the correct command It responds with: ls: cannot access /usr/include/GL: No such file or directory. I don't know what could be the problem.

Comment: I would like to say that as good as this site is you would do better on Ubuntu forums at ubuntu.com because here there can be no discussion. Just a specific question and a definite answer. Whereas on the forums we can post back and forth.

Comment: Rather than back and forthing can you just edit your question with the information of the steps you've done so far?

Answer (score 71):

Your instructions seem to be old, as far as I know glut is provided by the package freeglut3, to get it with the header files for development, install:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

[freeglut3-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/freeglut3-dev)[image: Install freeglut3-dev]

which should also pull in [freeglut3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/freeglut3)[image: Install freeglut3].

To have found this on your own, you could have done:

```
sudo apt-cache search glut
```

After you have installed package `freeglut3-dev` you can confirm it contains the needed GL files by issuing

```
dpkg -L freeglut3-dev
```

which will list contents of the package which include :

```
/usr/include/GL
/usr/include/GL/freeglut.h
/usr/include/GL/freeglut_ext.h
/usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h
/usr/include/GL/glut.h
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.a
...
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so
```

Comment: Also install `sudo apt-get install libxmu-dev libxi-dev`

Comment: `freeglut3-dev` isn't getting installed. Getting this error: `The following packages have unmet dependencies: freeglut3-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or libgl-dev but it is not going to be installed. Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or libglu-dev. E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`. Ubuntu 20.04.1. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Thank you for the comment about `apt-cache search`.  It great learning the tools to solve specific problems without having to sift through all of the documentation or man-pages (I like documentation, but it takes time which can be hard to carve out).

Answer (score 22):

To install OpenGL libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

To install freeGlut:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

Enter the following COMMANDS using Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install freeglut3-dev
```

**Additional Notes:**
If computer asks you if you accept its solution that `freeglut3-dev` shall NOT be installed due to dependencies, enter "**n**" to signify "**NO**".

The computer shall then notify you regarding the `downgrade` packages action to resolve the dependencies problem. Enter "**Y**" to signify "**YES**".

I hope this helps you too.

Thank you.